# docker pgadmin connect to Postgres failing

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to run pgadmin and postgres on docker. both services seems to work. However to able to connect to postgres through pgadmin. return password incorrect even after typing the password you see in the docker-compose file.

### docker-compose

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: danny329
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: danny329
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin

    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

### Error screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Note: the password i used is 'danny329'

Comment: What is the database host name that you use on pgadmin?

Comment: Im running postegres as a service as well... so it was diffcult to find the hostname, but found a solution which mentioned to use host.docker.internal instead. If you know any other way to find the hostname, that would be helpful.

Comment: When you browse to pgadmin home page, there will be a dialog asking you the database host name. What do you put for this field?

Comment: I didn't receive a dialog as such, only to enter password.

Comment: [This](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/server_dialog.html#server-dialog) is the (connection tab) dialog where you specify the database host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both your postgres container and pgadmin container are running on the same  Docker bridge network, you can connect them to each other using thier container name. For more info see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

In this case for the pgadmin you can set the hostname to be `postgres`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, providing the container name , that worked.